# How to extract feature of a specific pixel of an image using SURF?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, surf

SURF extracts features of key points of an image. I want to extract the feature of a specific pixel of an image. I wrote a code in MATLAB but it shows some errors.

The code is given below:

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
[row, col] = size(img);

for i=1:row
    for j=1:col
        points = img(i,j);
        [features, points] = extractFeatures (img, points);
    end
end
```

Comment: could you tell us about the error?

Comment: The errors are: Error using extractFeatures
Expected input number 2, POINTS, to be one of these types:

int16, uint16, int32, uint32, single, double

Instead its type was uint8.

Error in extractFeatures>checkPoints (line 403)
validateattributes(points,{'int16', 'uint16', 'int32', 'uint32', ...

Error in extractFeatures>parseInputs (line 226)
    checkPoints(points);

Error in extractFeatures (line 162)
[blockSize, SURFSize, descriptor,upright] ... sorry for being late

Comment: Thanks I got my answer. We have to pass the surf point object as the parameter of extractFeatures() method. We can easily convert the image co-ordinates to surf points by SURFPoints() matlab build in function.